# Add a backslash before some characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

Given the string "a|bc\de,fg~h,ijk,lm|no\p" what is the best way to add a '\' before the '|' ',' '~' and '\'

So the end string would be "a\|bc\de\,fg\~h\,ijk\,lm\|no\p"

What is the best way to do this?

I need this in c#.

Then i also need a way to get this string in JavaScript and remove all extra backslashes.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Can any one help me the the javacsript function that will give me back the original string, take off the extra `\`?

Comment: What happened around your `~h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex would be overkill.  Use [String.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
string myString = @"a|bc\de,fg~h,ijk,lm|no\p";

myString = myString.Replace("|", "\\|").Replace(",", "\\,").Replace("~", "\\~").Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

This produces `"a\|bc\\de\,fg\~h\,ijk\,lm\|no\\p"`

There's probably more than one way to get the string out for JavaScript.  It will depend on where you're generating the string.  For illustration purposes, say you're generating the string in the code behind and putting it in some control (like a hidden field, perhaps) on the client.

In the client you would get the string and use the Javascript String.Replace method, something like this, assuming str1 is `"a\|bc\\de\,fg\~h\,ijk\,lm\|no\\p"`:

```
str1 = str1.Replace("\,", ",");
str1 = str1.Replace("\|", ",");
str1 = str1.Replace("\\", "\");
```

It's been a while since I've done JavaScript, so you may need to escape the backslash with another backslash (like `\\`).

Comment: Thank you, that is great. can you also provide me with a javascript function that will get that string and remove all extra backslashes?

Comment: I've added some stuff for JavaScript that should hopefully point you in the right direction.  As I said in my answer, it's been a while since I've done JavaScript.

Comment: the c# was fine the  but the javascript didnt do the trick, but any way i need to do something else...

Comment: @Ovi - sorry.  Been a long time since I've done anything with JavaScript (been mostly in the data layer and middle-tier the last few years).  Glad the C# helped you out though.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to escape only `Regex system characters`, you can use the method `Escape` like that:

```
String str1= Regex.Escape("your string with \ - +");
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to escape all and every character individually, put @ before the string, for example:

```
string String = @"a|bc\de,fg~h,ijk,lm|no\p";
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to escape every character - you don't need to escape | and ,.  He's trying to add a backslash `\` in front of the pipes (|) and commas (,).